# Is it possible to make it clear if the application run under the root of the site or under an application in js

Tags: javascript

When deploy the application , it may be deployed under a port directly(a web site in IIS) like this:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Or under a directory(a directory in IIS) like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/appname
```

Then I wonder if I can get the root path of the appliation?

---

Why I ask this question:

In my appliation, I have lots of javascript files, and they would need to know the root path of the applciaiton, for example, it will create a icon, and the image is saved under the `/images` path under the root of the app, then in this case, how to dertime the location of the image path?

Comment: I assume you're talking about client-side Javascript, in which case, no. The application root is a server-side concept. You could cook up some "rules" to determine it based on the URL, but you'll be forever running into exceptions to those rules. What's your server-side technology? You could get your server-side to dynamically produce a JS file which includes a variable indicating the application root. But... my suspicion is you've got another issue you're not telling us, and JS is probably the wrong way to solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript does not know what directory are you running your application from, only the url of the current site - it does not know, if the host is e.g. [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), [stackoverflow.com/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), or [stackoverflow.com/questions/16952967](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952967). The best way to deal with that would be to compute such information server-side.

But if you're not using much of url rewriting and most of the time application is run from the main directory, you can create url using information available in window.location:

`var url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname`